# Fetch an embedded document mongodb Symfony2

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony

Maybe someone can help me with this issue.
I have the following document:

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\Document
 */
class guest {

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id(strategy="NONE")
     * @var string
     */
    protected $guest_id;


    /**
     * @MongoDB\String
     */ 
    protected $last_name;


    /**
     * @MongoDB\String
     */
    protected $first_name;


    /**
     * @MongoDB\String
     */
    protected $gender;


    /**
     * @MongoDB\EmbedMany(targetDocument="address")
     */    
    protected $address;
```

and the address document is here:

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\EmbeddedDocument
 */
class address {

    /**
     * @MongoDB\String
     */
    protected $street;


    /**
     * @MongoDB\String
     */
    protected $city;


    /**
     * @MongoDB\String
     */
    protected $zip_code;


    /**
     * @MongoDB\String
     */
    protected $country;
```

And here is a document:

```
    "_id" : "JM15061985",
    "last_name" : "Michel",
    "first_name" : "Justine",
    "gender" : "Female",
    "title" : "Mme",
    "telephone" : 3375,
    "mail" : "justine.michel@yahoo.com",
    "language" : "French",
    "birthday" : ISODate("1985-06-14T22:00:00Z"),
    "status" : "VIP",
    "company" : "Test",
    "address" : [
        {
            "street" : "45 Avenue de Paris",
            "city" : "Nice",
            "zip_code" : "06072",
            "country" : "France"
        },
]
```

And now I want to display those information in Twig, so I created the following using the querybuilder:

```
   public function guestAction()
   {     
       $guest = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')
                     ->getManager()
                     ->createQueryBuilder('KpqBundle:guest')
                     ->field('address.city')->equals('Nice')
                     ->getQuery()
                     ->execute();
       return $this->render('KpqBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('guest' => $guest));
    }
```

Then in the Twig view, I created this loop to display the information:

```
{% for i in guest %}
  {{ i.firstname }}
  {{ i.lastname }}
{% endfor %}
```

But how can I get the address fields? I tried something like `{{ i.city }}` but it gives me the following error:

```
Method "city" for object "Kpq\KpqBundle\Document\guest" does not exist in PmsBundle:Default:index.html.twig at line 59
```

And if I try this: `{{ i.address }}`, I get the following error:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\PersistentCollection could not be converted to string") in KpqBundle:Default:index.html.twig at line 59.
```

The last error is normal as I am trying to display an array I guess...

How can I query those address fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your query is ok. As the error messages states, the problem is that you are trying to display an object which can't be casted to a string.

**TL;DR**

Use `{{ i.address[0].city }}`

**Why is that?**

`{{ i.address }}` is of type [Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\PersistentCollection](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/mongodb_odm/1.0/class-Doctrine.ODM.MongoDB.PersistentCollection.html). A collection is an object that contains several other objects (of type address in your case). This collection class implements the [*ArrayAccess*](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) interface which is build into PHP.

You can use objects that implement this interface like any normal PHP array, meaning you can use `object[0]`, `object[1]` to get the first and the second item in the collection. In Twig there are [several ways](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#variables) to access arrays. One of those is using the `foo['bar']` notation, just like you are used to in PHP. So, the city of the first address can be accessed using `{{ i.address[0].city }}`.

`{{ i }}` This is your *guest* object.
`{{ i.address }}` is the collection of addresses.
`{{ i.address[0] }}` is the first entry in the collection, of type *address*.
`{{ i.address[0].city }}` is a string.

**Looping**

You can [loop](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable) over your addresses as well:

```
{% for address in i.address %}   
  <address>
    {{ address.street }}<br>
    {{ address.zip_code }}, {{ address.city }}<br>
    {{ address.country }}   
  </address> 
{% endfor %}
```

---

By the way, please start you class names with an upper case letter. Capitalising class names is considered a good practice in PHP and many other languages.

Comment: Thanks very much man!!!! I've been looking for that for long time now and thanks for the explanation!!